# I want image preview before uploading it using angular

Tags: angularjs

I am New to angularjs I am trying to achieve image preview befor its uploading with isolated scope in  file browser directive.

This is my html code

```
<div class="content">
                    <div class="field">
                        <label for="form-bridge-logo1">Logo 1</label>
                        <input id="form-bridge-logo1"  type="text" value=""  ng-model="myFile.name" />
                        <button class="clear-file" ng-if="myFile.name" ng-click="clear(myFile)"></button>
                        <input type="file" id="browse-file-logo1" ng-model="test" name="cover" file-browser="myFile" my-file="myFile" multiple data-logo-type="primary" class="browse-file-input" accept="image/jpg, image/jpeg, image/png"/>
                        <label for="browse-file-logo1" class="browse-btn">Browse</label>
                    </div>
                    <span class="remove-file" ng-if="myFile.name" ng-click="clear(myFile)">Remove</span>
                </div>
                <div class="content">
                    <div class="field">
                        <label for="form-bridge-logo2">Logo 2</label>
                        <input id="form-bridge-logo2" type="text"  ng-model="myFile1.name"/>
                        <button class="clear-file" ng-if="myFile1.name" ng-click="clear(myFile1)"></button>
                        <input type="file" id="browse-file-logo2" name="cover" file-browser="myFile1" multiple data-logo-type="secondary" class="browse-file-input" accept="image/jpg, image/jpeg, image/png"/>
                        <label for="browse-file-logo2" class="browse-btn">Browse</label>
                    </div>
                    <span class="remove-file" ng-if="myFile1.name" ng-click="clear(myFile1)">Remove</span>
                </div>
```

and I want image preview in following div

```
 <div class="rectangle-11">
                            <div ng-if="myFile.name" class="preview-container">
                                <img ng-src="{{imageSrcForPreview}}" alt="Logo 1" class="preview">
                            </div>
                            <div ng-if="myFile1.name" class="preview-container">

                                <img ng-src="{{imageSrcForPreview}}" alt="Logo 2" class="preview">
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

my directive is as follows

```
module.exports =  function($log, $parse, backendService, sharedServices, fileReader) {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        scope: {
            myFile: "="
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, sharedServices) {
            var model = $parse(attrs.fileBrowser);
            var modelSetter = model.assign;
            element.bind("change", function(e) {
                scope.fileForImagepreview = (e.srcElement || e.target).files[0];
                if (scope.fileForImagepreview.type === "image/jpeg" || scope.fileForImagepreview.type === "image/jpg" || scope.fileForImagepreview.type === "image/png") {
                    scope.$apply(function($scope) {
                        modelSetter(scope, element[0].files[0]);
                    });
                };
                var promise = fileReader.readAsDataURL(scope.fileForImagepreview, scope)
                  promise.then(function(result) {
                    scope.imageSrcForPreview = result;
                  });
            });
        }
    };
};
```

and service contains this function.

```
this.readAsDataURL = function(file, scope) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        var reader = this.getReader(deferred, scope);
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        return deferred.promise;
    };
```